# Is there any natural source of entropy when running `forge test`?

Tags: randomness, foundry, forge, random

I'm looking for a pseudo-random value that is different each time the command is run.

Either `forge test` or `forge script`.

Comment: You might want to consider [foundry-random](https://github.com/joejordan/foundry-random) though it's quite slow according to [this comment](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/5407#issuecomment-1637054502)